# Helm Templating nil pointer

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

This is the template I prepared but it gives an error. This is the error I got when I prepared and printed this helm, and I could not manage to read the characters here from the values.yaml file

**virtual-service.yaml**

```yaml
{{ $prefix := .Values.virtualservice.prefix }}
{{ $uri := .Values.virtualservice.uri }}
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
  kind: VirtualService
  metadata:
    name: {{ .Values.deploy.svc.name }}-virtual-service
    namespace: {{ .Values.deploy.namespace }}
  spec:
    gateways:
    - istio-system/istio-gateway
    hosts:
    - {{ .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: {{ $prefix }}
      rewrite:
        uri: {{ $uri }}
      route:
      - destination:
          host: {{ .Values.deploy.svc.name }}-service
          port:
            number: 80
```

and **values.yaml**

```yaml
virtualservice:
  enabled: true
  prefix: v1
  uri: /
```

**Helm Version:**

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.15.2", GitCommit:"8dce272473e5f2a7bf58ce79bb5c3691db54c96b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.15.2", GitCommit:"8dce272473e5f2a7bf58ce79bb5c3691db54c96b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

and **error**

````
Error: render error in "helm/templates/virtual-service.yaml": template: helm/templates/virtual-service.yaml:1:21: executing "helm/templates/virtual-service.yaml" at <.Values.virtualservice.prefix>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.prefix```
````

Answer (score 3):

Helm is complaining about unresolved variable `virtualservice.uri` (in the first line). You need to add it to the `values.yaml` or pass it to the helm invocation, e.g.:

```
helm template [NAME] [CHART] --set virtualservice.uri="whatever"
```